# Фильтр категорий для списка django в админке

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Ситуация следующая: нужно чтобы на основе одного списка в админке формировался другой:

Есть список помещений, в каждом помещении свои категории мебели.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы в списке "Категория" отображались только те категории, которые принадлежат выбранному помещению, а не все сразу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код моделей:

```
#Номенклатура товаров
class Items(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Наименование товара')
    cost_of = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Стоимость товара (руб)')
    discount = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Скидка (0 - без скидки)')
    main_photo = models.ImageField(verbose_name=u"Главное фото", upload_to=get_file_path)
    room = models.ForeignKey('TypesRooms', verbose_name='Помещение')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Categories', verbose_name='Категория')

#Список помещений
class TypesRooms(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Наименование помещения')

#Список категорий
class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Наименование категории')
    room = models.ForeignKey(TypesRooms, verbose_name='Помещение')
```

Comment: Без/с перезагрузкой страницы при выборе Помещения? Хотя сам понимаю, что лучше вариант получать данные AJAX запросом (если много категорий). А так в принципе можно на чистой JS сделать: в массив/объект (ассоциативный массив) изначально данные выгружать, а на стороне клиента менять при изменении select Помещение.

Comment: @AlexanderBragin других вариантов совсем нет? Не хотелось бы шаманить с переопределением шаблонов админки и представлений. Подойдет вариант формировать один список, но с подкатегориями. Пример: http://i015.radikal.ru/1201/28/eae690b972a0.jpg

Comment: Тогда думаю нужно смотреть в сторону — искать: **django optgroup select**. Например, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices или https://dealingit.wordpress.com/2009/10/26/django-tip-showing-optgroup-in-a-modelform/ или https://blog.laplante.io/2015/04/emulating-nested-optgroups-in-django-forms/ или https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/200/

Comment: Но я бы всё равно делал так, что при выборе Помещения подгружались соответстувующие категории — это будет удобнее для пользователей. Подгружать ли через AJAX, или делать это просто JavaScript-«массивом» — выбор за вами. Я бы AJAXом делал. Первый раз, да, возможно придется «шаманить», но потом будет проще. Мало ли где подоные задачи будут. С Django давно не работал, но очень хорошая система. С первых дней в ней проблем не было.

Comment: @AlexanderBragin Окей. Решил все таки встроить скрипт в шаблон. Я разобрался с тем, как переопределить шаблон. Не могу найти инфу, куда засунуть в этот шаблон ту инфу, которая мне нужна. Не подскажете, куда копать?

Comment: хотите добавить JavaScript-файл? Вроде этого https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014719/adding-a-jquery-script-to-the-django-admin-interface ?

Comment: @AlexanderBragin Скрипт встроил. Не могу понять, как мне передать в этот скрипт все категории. Шаблон же как-то составляет список из категорий. Не пойму еще, как происходит сохранение. Дело в том, что в списке нет никакой полезной информации кроме названия категории. А в разных помещениях могут находится одинаковые категории.